# Compare Cox with ANN

Tags: cox-model

I am trying to compare Cox model with ANN  by R but I have some problems.

1. the result of package `coxph` is hazard but the result of package `nnt` is survival  time
2. How to create labels in ROC curve in `rocr` package.
3. How to calculate concordance  indexes  by which package.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer the question, but can you explain *why* you want to compare the two directly? They tend to serve different purposes, so maybe saying how to compare them might not do you a favor.

ANNs are typically used to predict the expected survival for a subject with given covariates but offer limited interpretability (black box models). Cox PH models are rarely used for predictions, but rather to estimate effect sizes of covariates on survival (e.g. hazard ratios) to *explain* why certain subjects have a given survival time (white box models). That said, you can get predictions out of Cox PH models too.

ROC curves are used to evaluate *classifiers*. Both of your models in this context are doing regression and therefore you should use regression scores rather than ROC curves.